# How do you model a scalar response using a scalar IV, a categorical IV and categorical covariate w/ interactions?

Tags: interaction, ancova

So I originally thought I would be able to solve this problem fairly easily with ANCOVA, but now that I've thought more deeply about it I realized it is not so simple.

Essentially we have a scalar response variable, $y$ which we want to predict using three variables $x$, $c$ and $g$. $x$ is a scalar variable (which takes three values -3, 0, 3), $c$ is a categorical variable (which takes three values C1, C2, and C3) and $g$ is a categorical variable which takes two values (Y or N).

The issue is that $g$ was not an independent variable in the design of the experiment, but a covariate that was measured during the experiment.

Further, we have reason to believe that this covariate may interact with the other two variables in how it predicts $y$.

How do we design a model that is able to both consider the fact that $g$ is a covariate and allow us to analyze interactions between our three predictors.

Ideally, if whoever is capable of answering this can provide matlab code to solving this problem, that would be wonderful. However, even a way to create the design matrix for a general linear model would be immensely helpful.

Also, if I am approaching this entire problem from an incorrect perspective, I'm very open to other approaches to analyzing this data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd just do linear regression; I find it easier to understand.

Start with the design matrix for the simplest model: include a column of 1's for the intercept, then $x$, then indicators for $c =$ C2 and $c =$ C3 (that is, a column that is 1 when $c =$ C2 and 0 otherwise, and a column that is 1 when $c =$ C3 and 0 otherwise), then an indicator for $g=$ Y.  So that design matrix has 5 columns.

To expand the design matrix to allow for an interaction between $x$ and $g$, you'd include the product of the $x$ and $g$ columns.  To allow for an interaction between $c$ and $g$, you'd include two extra columns, the products of each of the $c$ columns with the $g$ column: the indicator "$c =$ C2 and $g = $ Y", and then "$c =$ C3 and $g = $ Y".  With both interactions, you'd have a design matrix with 8 columns.

To test for the interactions, you'd compare the residual sum of squares of the full model (with 8 columns) to the reduced model (with 5 columns).  Look at the [wikipedia page on the F test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test).

Comment: (+1) It might help to be more specific about what you mean by "compare the residual sum of squares" (such as the test statistic and it's null distribution).

Comment: @Macro, good point, thanks, though rather than explain fully I've just added a link to the wikipedia page on the F test.

Comment: @Karl - Is that still appropriate to do given that $g$ is itself not independently distributed w.r.t. $y$, since it was not an independent variable?

Comment: @ThisIstheId - It's perfectly fine to do, though the meaning of things change.  But it's very hard to say much about this or your final request above ("Also, if I am approaching this entire problem from an incorrect perspective, I'm very open to other approaches to analyzing this data.") without knowing a bit about the context: just what are y, x, c and g?